# complement image- read the rgb values from the pixels of an image and implement appropriate transformation function

Tags: java, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have been struggling with a small problem in my opinion. I have the task of implementing a transformation function to make a given image a complement image. My code works and outputs and image that has different colours, however im not sure if the function is truly transforming the hues that are complements of each other. I have included the most important part of my code for reference. Any Pointers?

```
float hue,sat,brightness;
int rgbValues;

float[]hsbVals=Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green , blue , null );
hue=hsbVals[0];
sat=hsbVals[1];
brightness=hsbVals[2]; 

rgbValues=Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, sat, brightness);
red=(rgbValues << 16)& 0xFF;
green=(rgbValues << 8) & 0xFF;
blue= rgbValues & 0xFF;


/* Put these values into imageTwo */
imageTwo.setRGB(x, y,red, green, blue);
 }
}
```

Comment: why do you convert them to hsb and back to rgb?

Comment: i'm not sure the actual reasoning behind converting back to rbg but i followed this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530167/complementary-colours-image-analysis/

Comment: That's not the full algo, try reading the question and answers in detail.

Comment: Yeah i fink she is looking for a more efficient method. I just want to turn a given image with its colours into a complement of itself. My question is, is there anything wrong with my implementation above?

Comment: yes, you convert rgb values to hsb and then back again with no purpose or effect, and you never alter the values.

Comment: So you're saying if I just convert the values to hsb then alter the hue for example, I will get my complement image?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to "unpack" the RGB integer here:

```
red=(rgbValues << 16)& 0xFF;
green=(rgbValues << 8) & 0xFF;
blue= rgbValues & 0xFF;
```

But you are shifting the wrong way. See [Color.getRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29).

```
red = (rgbValues >>> 16) & 0xFF;
green = (rgbValues >>> 8) & 0xFF;
blue = rgbValues & 0xFF;
```

Right now you aren't doing anything to get the complement. You are getting different colors because your left shifts result in red and green always being 0. If by complement you mean [complementary colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) you need to rotate the hue by 180 degrees.

```
float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(Color.CYAN.getRed(), Color.CYAN.getBlue(), Color.CYAN.getGreen(), new float[3]);
hsb[0] = hsb[0] + 0.5f > 1.0f ? hsb[0] - 0.5f : hsb[0] + 0.5f;
Color shouldBeRed = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]));
```

Comment: yah i just need to rotate the hue by 180 but i didn't know the coding for it...thanks

Comment: do you think this is correct?
hue= hue + 0.5f > 1.0f ? sat - 0.5f : brightness + 0.5f;
because you used hsb and when i tried that line in netbeans, it gave me errors

Comment: I forgot the array index. Oops.